# WebBrowser control navigate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser

I would like to make a test , first of all redirecting to a blank page and then just after redirecting to a normal page, but it looks like it doesnt make the second redirect ...

```
Browser.Base = Constants.ParkInfoDirectory;    //  "ParkInfo" folder
string s = string.Format("{0}/section_{1}.html", _parkId, _parkPage);    
//  URL = "/ParkInfo/ti217/5" for page 5 of Rainier

string blank = string.Format("{0}/Blank.html", _parkId);
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(blank, UriKind.Relative));
this.Browser.UpdateLayout();
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(s, UriKind.Relative));
this.Browser.UpdateLayout();
```

New version :

```
            string s = string.Format("{0}/section_{1}.html", _parkId, _parkPage);    //  URL = "/ParkInfo/ti217/5" for page 5 of Rainier
            string blank = string.Format("{0}/section_blank.html", _parkId);
            Uri blank_ = new Uri(blank, UriKind.Relative);
            Browser.Navigate(new Uri(blank, UriKind.Relative));
            Browser.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(Browser_Navigated);
            {
                if (e.Uri == blank_)
                {
                    Browser.Navigate(new Uri(s, UriKind.Relative));
                }
            };
            Browser.Navigate(blank_);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call two navigate method in one `UI thread` execution. It can cause some issues with that. Try to put second `Navigate` inside `Dispatcher` to delay it execution or subscribe to `Navigated` event and call second `Navigate` from it

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(blank, UriKind.Relative));
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    Browser.Navigate(new Uri(s, UriKind.Relative)); 
});
```

Or:

```
Uri blank_ = new Uri(blank, UriKind.Relative)
Browser.Navigated += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Uri == blank_)
    {
        Browser.Navigate(new Uri(s, UriKind.Relative)); 
    }
};
Browser.Navigate(blank_);
```

Comment: Lambda-expressions. You can also create event handler with `Browser.Navigated =` <Press Tab>, <Press Tab>

Comment: There is mixing of lambda-expressions and old-style in your code... Please, use only one approach you like more

Comment: `Navigated` event handler declared in another place, not even shown in your code. It not even compiles I think...